# Where does the "readme" field comes from in the artifact registry file

Tags: typescript, npm, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

We have private npm registry on Azure where we have our own npm package. It also stores the npmjs packages one of which is `@typescript-eslint/parser` we've noticed that the pipelines fails on `npm install` task with the `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input...`

```
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6744568Z npm http fetch GET 200 https:/EDITED.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/EDITED-Artifacts/npm/registry/@typescript-eslint%2fparser 216884ms
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6745003Z npm verb teardown shutting down workers.
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6745278Z npm info teardown Done in 0s
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6745630Z npm verb stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...odebase, don't forget'
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6746036Z npm verb stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6746533Z npm verb stack     at parseJson (C:\temp\_work\_tool\node\8.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6747277Z npm verb stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\temp\_work\_tool\node\8.17.0\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6747811Z npm verb stack     at <anonymous>
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6748134Z npm verb stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6748474Z npm verb cwd C:\temp\_work\4\s
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6748696Z npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.18362
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6749157Z npm verb argv "C:\\temp\\_work\\_tool\\node\\8.17.0\\x64\\node.exe" "C:\\temp\\_work\\_tool\\node\\8.17.0\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ci"
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6749618Z npm verb node v8.17.0
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6749914Z npm verb npm  v6.13.4
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6750208Z npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...odebase, don't forget'
2020-03-30T14:10:52.6750526Z npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
```

We've noticed that this package description file contains the `readme` field which bumps the size of it (the `@typescript-eslint%2fparser` description JSON is 5.5MB, stripped out of the `readme` field only 1.5MB) dramaticaly. Is this field added by the Azure registry or is it the package author addition or something else?

Is there a way to get rid of that field?

Answer (score 0):

The above error can be caused by a cache error or a bad package-lock.json file.

You can try running `npm cache clean --force` before npm install the package.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @typescript-eslint/parser
```

If it still doesnot work, try removing package-lock.json file.

If above solutions cannot fix the error, you can check if there is a error in the place where the `...odebase, don't forget` resides in your package.

You can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468) for more information